# Ruby on Rails Countdown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, countdown, countdowntimer

I want to add a visible Countdown in the header.

My website is to 95% the same as in the classic [Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl](https://www.railstutorial.org/).

The countdown should restart every 48 hrs and start a specific function to clear all microposts made in these 48 hours.
How would you do this?

I have been searching for hours but I can't find a working gem ([this one](https://github.com/jnbt/countdown) could work, but it doesn't).

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: You'll need to answer the most important question: **What have you tried**? A wild stab is better than nothing. There's probably no gem for this because it's not that complicated. Try and unpack the problem step by step.

Answer (score 0):

A timer like this needs at least two components:

1) A saved state in the database. This is generally a single DateTime field representing the DateTime when the countdown is expected to end. You can easily find the seconds remaining on the countdown with: `endTime - Time.now`.

2) A javascript front-end. Most timers online receive a single value from the server representing the time the countdown is expected to end (as mentioned above). They use this value to calculate the starting number on the timer and then "animate" the countdown by calling a method roughly every second to update the timer.

Making new database entries is a basic part of Rails, so if you don't know how to do it yet, look at some beginner tutorials for reference.

Javascript front-ends for timers are *very* common, so a google search for "javascript timer" should give you plenty of resources.

Take a stab at implementing those. If you get stuck, you can come back to stackoverflow with a question showing your code and what's not working- we'll be happy to help.